# remotely debug assembly from GAC

Tags: visual-studio-2015, remote-debugging

I have an assembly registered in GAC for x86 on a Win10-machine. The assembly was compiled for .NET 4.5. Now I´m trying to debug this assembly remotely for the sake of determining a customers issue with it.

Thus I launched msvmon.exe from my host where the assembly is located. I also installed the appropriate pdb-file on my debugging-machine and set the path indicated by Debug-->Options-->Debugging-->Symbols appropriately, as shown in the imagbe below.

[image]

Now when I type the hosts name and port where msvmon is running into the "attach-to-process"-window and add a breakpoint into the source-code it isn´t hit. In particular it states "no symbols are loaded for the current document".

[image]

On the other hand when I try to debug an assembly which is not located in the GAC I can easily debug it - even though I didn´t specify the path to the pdb-files (I unchecked the pdb-location from the first image to verify this). Therefor I´m pretty sure there is no network-related issue.

So I wonder where VS looks for the pdb-files when the assembly is regsitered in the GAC.

Comment: It depends on how the assembly was built.  Lower odds for a Release build but with default settings it still records the original location of the PDB.  Just have a look-see, use Debug > Windows > Modules, locate the assembly in the list.  Right-click > Symbol Load Information.

Comment: @HansPassant That gave me an idea. So I tried to manually set the pdb-path to the exact same path shown in image 1. This led to the error "A matching symbol file was not found in this folder", although it was there. When I now copy that exact same pdb from that folder into the GAC the debugger can resolve the path and loads the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed the issue by putting the pdb-file into the GAC of my debugging machine also.

So even when the path to the pdb-file is indicated by Debug-->Options-->Debugging-->Symbols this doesn´t seem to work for assemblies from GAC. You have to put the pdb-files next to the assembly. Usually we won´t even need the assembly on our debugging-machine. However I´m not sure if this also applies in this scenario.

Anyway this also applies if you debug locally. When an assembly is located in the GAC also its pdb-file needs to stay there.